# Abort Core Dumped in linux for a C++ progam that works in Visual Studio

Tags: c++

I have a C++ project that was built and runs in Visual Studio.
When I try to run it in unix, it gives me 
Abort (Core Dumped)

I am using the g++ version 3.2.2
How do i Fix this program ? It needs to run in linux.

Comment: did you try to gdebug (gdb) that program, it may give you a hint where the problem lies ...

Answer (score 8):

First step is to learn how to use `gdb` or any of the other excellent debuggers for Linux.

That should be able to tell you exactly which source line caused the problem. Then work back from there.

Other than that, we can't really help without seeing that source code. Psychic debugging, whilst useful, is not a highly developed field of endeavour :-)

Comment: I second that.  You can run gdb on the core (gdb binary_file core_file) to see where it crashed (definitely use the "backtrace" command to see the call stack) or you can first load the program with gdb (gdb binary_file) and then use the "run" command to start the program running.  The nice thing about the the second way is that gdb has some features that only work when running the program.  The pitfall is that some bugs can be sensitive to the environment and running within gdb makes them go away.

Answer (score 1):

@All
Thanks a lot for your responses.I really appreciate it

My program worked with g++ 4.2.3. It was aborting with g++ 3.2.2.

The code that gave me the correct output in visual studio was

```
foundOpen = inStr.find("(");
foundClose = inStr.find(")");
string inGate;
inGate = inStr.substr(++foundOpen,foundClose-foundOpen);
```

But using g++, I had to make a small change to the substr function.

```
foundOpen = inStr.find("(");
foundClose = inStr.find(")");
string inGate;
inGate = inStr.substr(++foundOpen,foundClose-foundOpen-1);
```

I am also a beginner to using linux and don't know how to use gdb. Are there any good tutorials to learn gdb?

Comment: Modifying a variable (`++foundOpen`) and accessing it again in the same statement is generally undefined behavior - at the very least, the order can vary. The fact that it worked at all, ever, is sheer luck. You should modify the code so you change `foundOpen` on its own line, before the `substr`; then it should work in both compilers.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a flying guess: your program uses '`getch()`' and you found the function in the library `-lcurses` or `-lncurses` and are using that library, but your program crashes as you said.

The trouble is, that function requires a certain amount of setup to work - unlike the similarly named but rather different function that is available on Windows.

Welcome to the real world - different platforms have different functions in the standard APIs; sometimes, two platforms have a function with the same name but different meanings.

Comment: Note that `getch()` is not a standard API. Indeed, if it were standard, it would be in all platforms :)

Answer (score 0):

Another wild guess: **boolean initialization**, we got bit by this one. The boolean was initialized automatically using VC++2003 but on Linux it was not (thus either true or false, flip a coin...).

Took a while to debug since in our case it did not crash and was intermittent. I wanted to slap the programmer on the head for not initializing his variable!